# How to connect Google App Engine with MongoDB Atlas?

Tags: mongodb, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to connect Google App Engine with my existing MongoDB Atlas instance. The issue is that I cannot whitelist an IP directly as I would do it with a custom server. So I followed this tutorial for adding a VPC Network connection:

https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/serverless-vpc-access-private-mongodb-atlas

So I followed the tutorial and double checked my setup. Here is my VPC Setup:

1. I use the default network

[image]

2. My Network Peering. I added the blurred information to Atlas like in the tutorial.

[image]

3. My Connector. I added the IP u can see here to the IP Whitelist in Atlas

[image]

4. At the end I added this to my app.yaml file:

```yaml
vpc_access_connector:
  name: projects/<PROJECT_ID>/locations/europe-west3/connectors/mongo-connector
```

The connector and my appengine are both in europe-west3 region.

After redeploying I still getting this error:

[image]

My connection string looks like this: `mongodb+srv://[USERNAME]:[PASSWORD]@[CLUSTER_NAME]-pri.[SUBDOMAIN].mongodb.net/`

I'm using a M10 cluster which is required for peering.

So has anyone an idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: My guess is that you have incorrectly setup Atlas IP Whitelist Entry OR the App Engine VPC access connector is setup incorrectly. As a test, select "allow access from anywhere" and remove the connector. If that works, then you know the client code is working. The key message is **ReplicaSetNoPrimary** which indicates an Atlas firewall issue (you are connecting from an address that Atlas does not accept).

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for your reply! Thats a good point I tried that seems like that this is not the issue. My AppEngine still cannot connect even when I add the wildcard. Can I show u something which helps u to figure out what the issue could be?